# android listview : footer view auto fill parent

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a listview. i set position 20(last position), after i want add footer start 
item last listview to bottom.
description:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/miUWs.jpg

**i have set height footer view. but i don't.**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="10000dp"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="FOOTER"
        android:background="#cf9f99" />

</LinearLayout>
```

listview :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".demoAddListViewFooterActivity">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity :

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, listItem,
                                                        false);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);
        listItem.addFooterView(footer,
                               null,
                               false);
        listItem.setAdapter(adapter);
        listItem.setSelection(20);
```

can you help me.

Comment: not able to understand what you try to say

Comment: i want footerview auto fill parent when   listItem.setSelection(19);

Comment: you can see image result :

   http://i.stack.imgur.com/cWQNV.png
i want.
  http://i.stack.imgur.com/QDepi.png

Comment: it's not simple work. my opinion create custom listview, and add many code line. first scroll method override, and get position 19, resize footer based on saved screen width, height. add some animation it more hard.